# .Net Core Date.ToDateTime() converts in diffrent formats by language

Tags: c#, datetime

I create date objects based on strings with hour and minute values coming from a service.

Our app is multi-language, the default `Date.ToDateTime()` functions work differently in different languages. For example, `01/10/2022` becomes `January 10 2022` in some cultures and ``1 October 2022` in others.

What I want is make the function convert to January 10 2022 every time.

How can I do this?

**DateTime.Parse(dateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ->** [ss1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3ZGn.png)

Comment: It behaves according to the _[Culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-6.0)_ your app is running in. Are you looking to render a DateTime in the same format regardless of the current Culture?

Comment: You've already demonstrated how this is impossible - because "01/10/2022" can mean different things. Fundamentally, the service either needs to use a single data format, or needs to provide format information along with the data. (Either that, or I've misunderstood your question...)

Comment: In moment we can give the type of datetime and then format it , its ilke saying this date is mm/dd/yyyy and now you are formatting it to dd/mm/yyyy right, is there any way to make it in c#

Comment: Right now it's not even clear if you're parsing a string to a date or outputting a date to a string. Maybe show a little code sample and this will make more sense.

Comment: IMHO `DateTime.ParseExact(....)` since you know exactly what format you need to support. No Culture required.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Convert.ToDateTime()`, you can use [`DateTime.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse), which has overloads to accept an `IFormatProvider` where you can specify a specific culture.

```
var dateString = "01/10/2022";
DateTime result = DateTime.Parse(dateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// result will ALWAYS have January 10, regardless of culture on local system
```

See it here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/NzaYPK

The `DateTime.TryParse()` function can also do this. For completeness you should be aware of `DateTime.ParseExact()` and `DateTime.TryParseExact()` as well.

Comment: Sorry but that wont work in my case, i added ss

Comment: But what is the solved my problem is i will share it on top, thank you for your answer it helped

Answer (score 0):

The answer is improved version of @Joel Coehoorn 's answer.
GetCultureInfo("xx-XX")) xx like en-EN

```
Datetime newDate = DateTime.Parse(response.Result.TInfo.Date, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("xx-XX")).AddHours(hour).AddMinutes(minute);
```

Comment: Why is it an improvement? Can you [edit] your answer to provide more explanation, and to ensure your answer remains relevant as a stand-alone answer, without relying on @Joel’s explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide any of your desired Culture like "en-Us", "en-GB" etc. Then all of your datetime will be formatted like that.

```
DateTimeFormatInfo yourCultureFormat = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;

var result = Convert.ToDateTime("12/01/2011", yourCultureFormat)
```